# Ruby array [ ] how can I get rid of quotations on the browser

Tags: ruby, arrays

Simple question. I am using Ruby V1.9.3 and I type;

```
<%= f_array = ['a','b','c'] %><br>
<%= f_array.join(' , ') %><br>
```

but they show up on the browser as;

```
["a", "b", "c"]
a,b,c
```

As far as I remember (until Ruby V1.8.3), it used to show up like;

```
abc
a,b,c
```

Did Ruby change their specification or did I miss something??

Comment: Why are you using `<%= ... %>` around an assignment?

Answer (score 2):

You error is here

```
<%= f_array = ['a','b','c'] %>
```

The statement `<%=` represents a print statement. Change it to

```
<% f_array = ['a','b','c'] %>
```

and the line will not be printed. `["a", "b", "c"]` is the result of the inspection of an array.

```
2.1.5 :003 > puts ['a','b','c'].inspect
["a", "b", "c"]
```

For what it is worth, the code has another issue. Your view should not contain assignments. That's part of the business logic of your application.

Comment: "Your view should not contain assignments. That's part of the business logic of your application." +1

Comment: thank you for your comment! Yes, I understand that "<%= represents a print statement". I was just going over a book and the picture showed <%= f_array = ['a','b','c'] %> display on the browser with out  [ ] or  " " ...